# how can I request thumbnailImage from MPMoviePlayController while slider

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a custom UISider control, i send requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes to MPMoviePlayerController when i slider the control.

```
- (void)sliderPopoverView:(UISlider*)slider
{
    self.currentSliderValue = slider.value;
    [self.moviePlayer requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.currentSliderValue]]
                                             timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
} 

- (void)requestFinishThumbnail:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UIImage *thumbnailImage = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey];
    if (thumbnailImage) {
        _bottomView.sliderPopover.popover.thumbnailView.image = thumbnailImage;
    }  
}
```

then I can receive lots of image for show. but main Thread blocked. it's hard to slider the custom control. cost lots of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason may be that the method

```
- (void)sliderPopoverView:(UISlider*)slider
```

is called every time the slider is moved a little bit. This will cause your MPMoviePlayerController to constantly generate thumbnails. You should probably try to reduce the number of times you call the method that generates thumbnails.

Comment: yes, i also realize it. i create a Timer to request ThumbnailImage pre second. it also block main thread. it also slider the control time-consuming.

Comment: Do you schedule a new timer every time the slider is moved? Or do you schedule a new one when the old one has expired?

Comment: schedule a new timer every time the slider is moved.invalidate the timer when don't move

Comment: This will also cause your MPMoviePlayerController to generate a lot of thumbnails, because you schedule a lot of timers.

Comment: Yes, I know that thumbnails are generated asynchronously. Is requestFinishThumbnail: performed on the main thread?

Comment: yea,update UI preformed on the main thread.but this the reason? I am confused

Comment: If it's on the main thread then it's correct. I think you should try reducing the frequency of scheduling timers.

Comment: yes,it can solve this problem. but the thumbnail image wait for long to update. i want to see different thumbnail Image when slide the custom slider control. how can i solve it?